# How to show the actual node on a group-content page when using the Group module?

Tags: views, group

Creating a new group-content in [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module on Drupal 8 generates a normal node without any "live" context to the group. So viewing this node does not allow the group-actions block to work.

If you view the group-content reference page you can not see the actual content of the node, but the context is intact and you can use group-actions block.

How to show the actual node on this page?

I was thinking maybe using a view for full rendered content filtered by group-content-id. this is working fine as long as I use no aliases at all. 
So using `group/3/content/8` as url and filtering for group-content-id of 8 is working.

But how to filter for an alias like `www.example.com/mynewgroup/mynewgroupcontent`?

Comment: There is no [Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/groups) module ... please add a link to D.O to clarify the module your question is about.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the GROUP Module, not Groups. Link: https://www.drupal.org/project/group

Comment: Merci for the correction. Next question: what doe you mean by that ' ... "live" context to the group ...'? And what is 'group-actions block'? And what is 'the group-content reference page'? And what does the "new" refer ti in your "mynewgroup" and "mynewgroupcontent"? Please EDIT your question to clarify these things.